# Ajax.ActionLink Only Links to the Current Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an Ajax.ActionLink in a Partial View as follows:

```
<div id="accordion">
    @foreach (var m in Model)
    {
        var targetId = m + "_List";

        <h3 id="@(m)" class="thingModelHeader">
            @Ajax.ActionLink(m, "AjaxGetThings", "Perf",
                new AjaxOptions { 
                    HttpMethod="GET",
                    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                     UpdateTargetId= targetId,
                     Url="13412" 
                })
        </h3>
        <div id="@targetId"  >
            @* list will populate here when the link is clicked *@
        </div>

    }
</div>
```

I have a controller with the appropriate method:

```
public class PerfController : Controller
{
    [Route("AjaxGetThings/{id}", Name = "AjaxGetThings")]
    public PartialViewResult AjaxGetThings(string id)
    {
        IQueryable<Thing> results;

        using (var repo = new ReadOnlyRepository<Thing>())
        {
            things = repo.All()
                          .Where(p => p.Id == Id)
                          .OrderBy(p => p.Name)
                          ;
        }

        return PartialView("CustomPartialView", results);
    }

}
```

I have a ScriptBundle for the unobtrusive  validation:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
"~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

...and I reference it in my Layout page:

```
    </footer>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery-ui")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that no matter how I define the Action, Controller, or Url in the AjaxOptions the link always points to the current URL.  The target div loads and updates with a whole 'nuther version of the page - so it's *working* as far as the Ajax part of it goes, but no matter what I do the URL never points anywhere useful - like the actual controller and action that I have specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try specifying the url like this

```
url: 'Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { ID = m.targetid })'
```

Comment: how do I pass the id into that url?